# Getting rid of unwanted "suggested" contacts in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I have removed an old address from contacts in Gmail but it still keeps popping up the "suggestions" when I type in the `To` line—is there a magic way to get rid of it permanently?

Comment: Yes, delete it from _Other Contacts_.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you deleted it from *My Contacts* but not from *Other Contacts*. You should delete it from *Other Contacts* as well.